# How to solve this equation? $a^2 \cdot \arcsin(\frac 4a)+4 \cdot\sqrt {a^2-16}=40$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please, help me solve this equation:
$$a^2 \cdot \arcsin \left(\frac 4a \right)+4 \cdot\sqrt {a^2-16}=40$$

Comment: this is only possible by a numerical method

Comment: are there any real Solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Say $\frac{4}{a}=u$

Then the given equation becomes
$$\arcsin u + u\sqrt{1-u^2}=\frac{5}{2}u^2$$

Now $u$ must be such that $|u|<1$.

So we can assume that $u=\sin x$ or $\cos x$.

Now see if you can solve this trigonometric equation.

Answer (score 0):

There may not exist an explicit solution for $a$ in terms of elementary functions.

However, you can apply the [Newton-Raphson Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) (A numerical method) using a spreadsheet, or with more sophisticated software such as MATLAB:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)} \tag{1}$$

You have your function:

$$f(a)=a^2 \cdot \arcsin \left(\frac 4a \right)+4 \cdot\sqrt {a^2-16}-40$$

Differentiating it:

$$f'(a)=\frac{4a}{\sqrt{a^2-16}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-\frac{16}{a^2}}}+2a\arcsin\left(\frac{4}{a}\right)$$

Substituting into $(1)$:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n^2 \cdot \arcsin \left(\frac {4}{a_n} \right)+4 \cdot\sqrt {a_n^2-16}-40}{\frac{4a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2-16}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-\frac{16}{a_n^2}}}+2a_n\arcsin\left(\frac{4}{a_n}\right)} \tag{2}$$

Let us start with an initial value $a_0=11$. You can choose these values by simply 'guessing' a value close to the actual solution.

Now, substitute the value of $a_0$ for $a_n$, and find the value of $a_1$ using equation $(2)$. Continue this iteration until you get closer and closer to the value of $a$.

I get a value of $a\approx 5.52978022$.

Comment: are you sure of this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Does this not work for you?

Comment: i can not find this zero

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2*arcsin(4%2Fa)%2B4*sqrt(a%5E2-16)%3D40) suggests otherwise.

Comment: ok i have made a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about precision, then you can get an approximate solution by fixed point iteration instead of Newton-Raphson.

Using @SchrodingersCat's result, we have an equation:

$$u=\frac{2}{5} \left(\frac{\arcsin u}{u} +\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)$$

Take initial guess $u_0=1$ and substitute:

$$u_1=\frac{2}{5} \left(\frac{\arcsin u_0}{u_0} +\sqrt{1-u_0^2}\right)$$

$$u_2=\frac{2}{5} \left(\frac{\arcsin u_1}{u_1} +\sqrt{1-u_1^2}\right)$$

Then we get the following sequence of values (correct digits are highlighted):

$$\color{blue}{0}.6283185307179586$$
$$\color{blue}{0.7}436955340482698$$
$$\color{blue}{0.7}184422024307543$$
$$\color{blue}{0.72}45114408003248$$
$$\color{blue}{0.723}0826224901516$$
$$\color{blue}{0.723}4206633738902$$
$$\color{blue}{0.7233}407802435841$$
$$\color{blue}{0.72335}96627961654$$
$$\color{blue}{0.72335}51996817168$$
$$\color{blue}{0.723356}2546078128$$
$$\color{blue}{0.7233560}052606297$$
$$\color{blue}{0.7233560}641975273$$
$$\color{blue}{0.72335605}02669220$$
$$\color{blue}{0.72335605}35596262$$

> Thus, $u \approx 0.72335605$, so $$a=\frac{4}{u} \approx 5.52978$$